# Why is Twilio Alphanumeric sender ID failing silently?

Tags: twilio

I am trying to use the Twilio node library to send an SMS message from a UK Twilio number to a UK mobile number. It works fine when I don't put in the "alphanumeric senderId", and just a normal number. But when I swap it out it doesn't work!

```
const accountSid = 'SID';
const authToken = 'AUTH';
const twilio = require('twilio');
const client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);
const twilioNumber = "TWILIO_NUMBER";
const myNumber = "MY_NUMBER";
client.messages
  .create({
     body: "",
     from: twilioNumber, // Have tried replacing this with alphanumeric string!
     to: myNumber,
   })
  .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

When i execute this code, I don't get any error messages - but I also don't receive any logs!

How can I best debug this issue, and how do I get the alphanumeric sender Id to work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created an alphanumeric resource?
Take a look at this https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/services/api/alphasender-resource
You should create your alhpa id resource before using it to send messages.

Comment: Thanks, I just did this and have created an alphanumeric sId, but don't see how I can connect this to my Twilio phone number.

Comment: Check out this page https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181348-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-for-Twilio-Programmable-SMS
Hope it helps :)